# Obtaining a list of MediaBrowserServices currently registered results in only the bluetooth MediaBrowserService

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to build an app where one can start audio playback from WearOS.
From what I can tell this requires an app on the phone to obtain a list of possible songs to be played. To do that I want to use the MediaBrowserService, like [this example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-media-controller) does.

However when I try to reproduce the listing of MediaBrowserServices, I only get the "Bluetooth audio" MediaBrowserService. The example app on the other hand works fine and displays all apps.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val mediaBrowserIntent = Intent(MediaBrowserServiceCompat.SERVICE_INTERFACE)

    val packageManager = this.packageManager
    val services = packageManager.queryIntentServices(mediaBrowserIntent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER)
    val tv: TextView = findViewById(R.id.helloworld)
    val res = StringBuilder()
    for(info in services) {
        res.appendLine(info.serviceInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString())
    }
    tv.text = res.toString()
}
```

This is adapted from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-media-controller/blob/master/mediacontroller/src/main/java/com/example/android/mediacontroller/tasks/FindMediaBrowserAppsTask.kt#L46-L64).

Do you know what might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to properly handle the [package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility).
Try to add `<queries>` section to your manifest file with the correct intent filter signature:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

The sample app works because it targets SDK 29.